# What's the difference in how Nhibernate treats .FirstOrDefault vs .SingleOrDefault? possible bug?

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

Just starting out with NHibernate and using Nhib 3.0's (3.0.0.2001) Linq with following models

```
public class Request
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual State {get;set;}
}
public class State
{
    public virtual Guid Id {get;set;}
}
```

So I'm just trying to retrieve a Request based on it's State Id.

```
_session.Query<Request>().Where(x => x.State.Id==someGuidValue).FirstOrDefault();
```

Seems pretty straight forward, but this gets a sql error based on generated sql where it looks like @p0 parameter is missing, though not sure why'd it be included here.

```
{"Line 1: Incorrect syntax near '('."}
 select TOP (@p0) requ0_.Id as Id0_
, requ0_.State_id as State8_0_ 
from [Request] requ0_ where requ0_.State_id=@p1 ]
  Name:p1 - Value:a2e63925-6628-4786-a621-9e5200d5ab71
```

However, using SingleOrDefault works, just fine.

```
_session.Query<Request>().Where(x => x.State.Id==someGuidValue).SingleOrDefault();
```

Any insight would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe `SingleOrDefault` will error when more than one records meets your select criteria. Where `FirstOrDefault` will just pull the first regardless of how many records are returned.

That's how it works in LINQ-To-SQL